# problem on "rosdep install"

Tags: rosdep, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i did every command on this page and it was ok, but i have problem on this command! plz help me :(

mohsen@mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry_tutorials/turtle_tf$ **rosdep install AMAZING_PACKAGE**

**ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource AMAZING_PACKAGE**

ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros

ROS path [1]=/home/mohsen/fuerte_workspace

ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share

ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55538/problem-on-%22rosdep-install%22/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AMAZING_PACKAGE is only a place holder. You should replace that with the package that you want to install dependencies for.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on 2013-02-18**:
tnx :) plz help me there http://answers.ros.org/question/55522/problem-on-turtle_tf-missing-resource-catkin/